# Dynamic execution for procedure sp_dropserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following stored procedure that drops a linked server dynamically according to a passed server name

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[sprocServiceConfig_DropLinkedServer]
     (@ServerName NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT 
        @SQLQuery = N'master.sys.sp_dropserver  ''' + @ServerName+ ''' ,  ''droplogins'' '

    EXECUTE @SQLQuery
END
```

I can't execute `sp_dropserver` dynamically. I get the error

> Can't find stored procedure sp_dropserver

I can execute it in non-dynamic mode like

```
EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver 'Test-PC' , 'droplogins'
```

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the dynamic queries, you need to use `sp_executesql`.

Try changing from

```
 @SQLQuery = N'master.sys.sp_dropserver  ''' + @ServerName+ ''' ,  ''droplogins'' '

 EXECUTE @SQLQuery
```

TO

```
 @SQLQuery = N'EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver  ''' + @ServerName+ ''' ,  ''droplogins'' '

 EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [Common].[sprocServiceConfig_DropLinkedServer]
    (@ServerName VARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQuery VARCHAR(MAX)

    SELECT @SQLQuery = ''''+@ServerName+ ''' ,  ''droplogins'''

    EXEC master.sys.sp_dropserver  @SQLQuery
END
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass it in braces:

```
EXECUTE (@SQLQuery)
```